# Turning off CC button in Androids Youtube Library

Tags: android, youtube, closed-captions

I am trying to solve a problem i currently have with the Youtube player in a android app. I want to play a video with controls such as play, pauze, volume and fullscreen. The only Playermode as far as i know that does this is the default player. Problem is; this player mode has a CC button which makes my app crash because there is no CC in the video i'm playing. Can i remove this button somehow?Or can i make it so it doesn't do anything?

EDIT 1: This is a issue with the YouTube library. Source: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6974#makechanges

Is there someone who knows some kind of workaround?